# Nextcloud Server security & setup warnings using apache2 on ubuntu server

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php, nextcloud

[image]

In this I did try solving the red errors:

1. - PHP configuration option output_buffering must be disabled
     path: /etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini

```
; output_buffering
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: 4096
;   Production Value: 4096
```

As you can see all the things are changed yet the error is being showed.

2. - Your data directory and files are probably accessible from the internet. The .htaccess file is not working. It is strongly recommended that you configure your web server so that the data directory is no longer accessible, or move the data directory outside the web server document root.

path: /etc/apache2/sites-available and in that nextcloud.conf

**Code I changed is**

```
  GNU nano 6.2                                                                            nextcloud.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin **mymail**
    DocumentRoot /var/www/nextcloud/
    ServerName **my ip-address**

    Alias /nextcloud "/var/www/nextcloud/"
    Redirect 301 /.well-known/webfinger /nextcloud/index.php/.well-known/webfinger
    <Directory /var/www/nextcloud/>
      #  Options +FollowSymlinks
       # AllowOverride All
        
         Require all denied

         # Require all granted
       # <IfModule mod_dav.c>
        #    Dav off
       # </IfModule>
       # SetEnv HOME /var/www/nextcloud
       # SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/nextcloud
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

---

> ignore the http error, smtp and default_phone_region errors and warnings

---

Now for the remaining /.well-known/ warnings. How to solve them I have tried solving it and the code is

path: /etc/apache2/sites-available

In this I have 2 conf files and don't know which to modify so I did it on both one by one and yet warning did not go

```
000-default.conf  default-ssl.conf  nextcloud.conf
```

for nextcloud.conf and I tried solving one error /.well-known/webfinger

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin smssmit@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/nextcloud/
    ServerName 192.168.1.105

    Alias /nextcloud "/var/www/nextcloud/"

    Redirect 301 /.well-known/webfinger /nextcloud/index.php/.well-known/webfinger

    <Directory /var/www/nextcloud/>
      #  Options +FollowSymlinks
       # AllowOverride All
        Require all denied
         # Require all granted
       # <IfModule mod_dav.c>
        #    Dav off
       # </IfModule>
       # SetEnv HOME /var/www/nextcloud
       # SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/nextcloud
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

for 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/nextcloud
        
        Redirect 301 /.well-known/webfinger /nextcloud/index.php/.well-known/webfinger

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

In ServerAdmin do I have to add my email ?

So this are the main issues I want to solve them as it my first time using nextcloud.

Also listed on: https://help.nextcloud.com/t/security-setup-warnings-using-apache2-on-ubuntu-server/162643?u=smit_desai

Thank you.

Comment: This question does not adhere to our Q&A format. You have several unique problems: a PHP problem; a warning about .htaccess; a warning about no encryption; a memory caching problem; and a URL resolution problem. Each of these issues are entirely different and will have entirely different solutions. **Please don't combine multiple problems in a single question.** Ask multiple questions if necessary. You can link between the questions if they help provide context.

Comment: Setting up Nextcloud can be complicated, but the developers maintain excellent [documentation](https://docs.nextcloud.com/) including documentation specific to [server administration](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/stable/admin_manual/). Have you been using it? They include start-to-finish set up tutorials, including Ubuntu-specific documentation. Nextcloud has a lot of moving parts to work properly. Because you have so many issues it might be prudent to start over. FYI, there is a nextcloud server snap that *greatly* simplifies the process.